# Using result of spreadtab macro outside of table

Tags: macros, spreadtab

I have a spreadtab table and want to sum one of it's columns. I would like to use the result several times in my document. How do I go about doing that?

This code should explain what I am trying to accomplish.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ll}}
  \toprule @Col1 & @Col2 \\
  \midrule 
  2 & 2 \\
  3 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule   
  \newcommand{\totsum}{:={sum(b2;b3)}}
  & \totsum \\
\end{spreadtab}

Here I am using totsum outside of the table: \totsum \\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual

> **3.5  Save the result of a cell**
>
> It may be necessary to save the numerical value of a cell to display it outside a formula or even
>   outside the table. Here is how to do it: `\STsavecell{<control sequence>}{<absolute reference>}` With a `\global\def`, this command
>   globally saves in  the result of the formula
>   contained in the cell .
>
> Only absolute references
>   can be used since this command must be placed in the optional argument
>   of the spreadtab environment.
>
> In order to save several cells, the command `\STsavecell` can be put several times in the optionnal argument.

So with your MWE as a base

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell\totsum{b4}]{{tabular}{ll}}
  \toprule @Col1 & @Col2 \\
  \midrule 
  2 & 2 \\
  3 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule   
& :={sum(b2;b3)}
\end{spreadtab}

Here I am using totsum outside of the table: \totsum
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just would like to update from a different point of view. Today I ran in a similar problem. We wrote a bill and wanted to have the sum in the last line, a any result wherever. Then obviously we cannot reference with absolute path any longer. But the manual helped again:

From the manual ([spreadtab via CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab))

> **4.4  Coordinate macro functions**
>
> […]
>
> The macro function `tag(<name>)` gives a name to the cell in which it is located. This is not really a macro
>   function like the others, since it returns nothing when put in a formula and disappears without causing any
>   effect on the mathematical result. We can write `tag(<nom>)` anywhere in the numeric field of a cell. The `<name>`
>   can be any string of alphanumeric characters, but it is not advisable to put a letter and a number that could be
>   understood as a reference to a cell, and would therefore be modified at a copy operation with `\STcopy`. This
>   macro function has an additional action, it saves via a `\def` the numeric value of the cell in which it is located in
>   order to be able to use later outside the table via the purely expandable command `\STtag{<name>}` .

So to adopt the MWE would be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell\totsum{b4}]{{tabular}{ll}}
  \toprule @Col1 & @Col2 \\
  \midrule 
  2 & 2 \\
  3 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule   
& :={sum(b2;b3)tag(sumtot)}
\end{spreadtab}

Here I am using totsum outside of the table: \totsum{} or \STtag{sumtot}
\end{document}
```

Also I suggest two more alternations

1. the reference in the options `b3` results in 3 here, so made it `b4` – not sure if there was reason for naming `b3` and having this result still
2. calling `\totsum` without brackets kills the space afterwards, so needed them in this case for the addition

Comment: thx for nicer formatting @stefan-pinnow

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The `\STtag{foo}` option does indeed seem like quite a good alternative, especially in your use case.  On one of your comments, I think you caught an error in my answer to this question where the code posted (which evidently was not exactly the same code I used to generate the screenshot!) had `\STsavecell\totsum{b3}` which should indeed have referred to `b4` instead.  I've now corrected this in my answer, thanks for noticing!